# Creating array literals with various child classes of an interface in f#

Tags: casting, f#, list-literal

If I have the following interface

```
type IParameterizable =
    abstract member Parameters : unit -> seq<Parameter>
```

I then have some factories that create various sub-classes of IParameterizable

```
let MakeA arg = ...
let MakeB arg = ...
let MakeC arg = ...
```

where A, B, C are child classes of IParameterizable. Now if I wish to make an array
literal

```
let contents = [| MakeA 0; MakeB 1; MakeC 2 |]
```

the compiler complains that they are of different type. However if I do

```
let contents = [| MakeA 0 :> IParameterizable
                ; MakeB 1 :> IParameterizable
                ; MakeC 2 :> IParameterizable
                |]
```

this works but is a bit busy on the eyes. The obvious solution is to make the factories return IParameterizable rather than the concrete class but in other cases I need the concrete class rather than the interface.

Is there a way to only specify the type of the array once and then all elements
will be implicitly cast or a compiler error if the cast is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to define the type of the variable assigned to

```
let contents:IParameterizable array = 
           [| MakeA 0 
            ; MakeB 1 
            ; MakeC 2 
            |]
```

Type inference then kicks in on the literal and locks it down.

Comment: I think you can also use the inferred upcast feature: `MakeA 0 :> _`.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing you should mark this as the answer if it fixed your problem

Comment: I have to wait a couple of days before the system will let me mark my own answer as the correct one.